# Select distinct two columns and apply group by other columns

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table in which I want to extract unique combinations of two columns and group by other columns.

```
userid   itemid   version   start_date
uid1     itemid1  version1  2018-07-25 00:00:00
uid1     itemid2  version1  2018-07-25 00:00:00
uid1     itemid1  version2  2018-07-25 00:00:00
uid2     itemid3  version1  2018-07-26 00:00:00
uid2     itemid4  version1  2018-07-26 00:00:00
uid2     itemid2  version1  2018-07-26 00:00:00
uid2     itemid2  version2  2018-07-26 00:00:00
```

I want to find out count of unique combinations of userid and itemid group by version and start_date. Expected result is following

```
total     version    start_date
2         version1   2018-07-25 00:00:00
1         version2   2018-07-25 00:00:00
3         version1   2018-07-26 00:00:00
1         version2   2018-07-26 00:00:00
```

I know how to find distinct combination of multiple columns but facing problem in group by.

I tried applying count distinct of concatenate of userid and itemid and group by on version and start_date but it is taking too much time as table has billions of rows.

```
  select start_date, count(distinct(userid || '_' || itemid)), version
  from table name
  group by start_date, version;
```

Advised by @Jon

I am expecting duration not more than an hour. I am using 15 nodes of DS2 instance type(I have other data tables as well). start_date is a Dist key and itemid, userid, version are sort keys. It takes around 6 minutes to find distinct of userid and around 13-14 minutes when I apply group by version.

Comment: how much time do you expect? what is dist key? what is sort key? how many rows? what type of cluster (DS2?)? How many nodes in cluster? how much time does it take to get distinct count of just one of those columns? how much time does it take to run the query as is? (please add answers directly into your question)

Comment: Unrelated but: `distinct` is **NOT**  a function. `distinct (a)` is exactly the same thing as `distinct a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select
count(*),
version,
start_date from (
Select
userid, 
itemid,
version,
start_date,
Row_number() over(partition by userid , itemid order by itemid asc )  rnk 
from stack_check
) a
group by 
version,
start_date
order by start_date

Window function will help you to get what you are looking for.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_Window_functions.html

Comment: count version start_date
2 version1 2018-07-25 00:00:00
1 version2 2018-07-25 00:00:00
1 version2 2018-07-26 00:00:00
3 version1 2018-07-26 00:00:00

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. Thanks Ramakrishna.

Comment: @abhijeet . . . How is this answer better than using `select distinct` in a subquery?

Comment: @Gordon It is taking below 10 minutes.

Comment: @Ramakrishna Thanks for the help. I need some help with one another query.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51579015/find-top-1000-entries-along-with-count-and-rank-from-table   .If you don't mind, please have a look.

Comment: @abhijeet . . . How long did the query take with `select distinct` in a subquery?

Comment: @Gordon 2 hours 25 minutes. Which I was expecting as the table has ~30 B rows.

Comment: @abhijeet . . . I'm surprised that this is so much faster.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that Redshift does not efficiently implement `count(distinct)` because it serializes the distinct count.  That means that it is better to use a subquery with `select distinct`:

```
select start_date, version, count(*)
from (select distinct userid, itemid, version, start_date
      from table name
     ) t
group by start_date, version;
```

Comment: I used following query select start_date, version, count(*) as unique_combination_count 
from (select item_id, user_id, version, start_date 
from table_name
group by item_id, user_id, version, start_date) 
group by start_date, version;

Comment: I am using a same logic. Is it more efficient to use distinct to find all unique set of rows than using group by ?

Comment: @abhijeet . . . In some databases, `select distinct` is more efficient than `count(distinct)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a subquery to get the distinct columns and then a join for the count:

```
SELECT
COUNT(T2.itemID) AS total
,T1.[version]
,T1.[start_date]


FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT
        itemid
        ,[version]
        ,[start_date]

        FROM
        YourTable
    ) AS T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN
YourTable T2
ON T1.itemid = t2.itemid
    AND T1.[version] = T2.[version]
    AND T1.[start_date] = T2.[start_date]

GROUP BY
T1.[version]
,T1.[start_date]
```

Comment: I am afraid that joining table is not a best option for a table of such size.

Comment: Those square brackets are invalid in an identifier in standard SQL and Redshift

Comment: Apols, didn't notice the redshift tag